# How to simulate closing the lid?

Tags: power-management

I have probem with my laptops monitor. When I move my laptop, sometimes screen goes white, blank. Then I have to open and close lid. It is very annoying because when I open it its moves and turn white again. I though about makeing key to simulate closing and opening my lid. Is there a way to do this? Some script, some command?

Comment: Sounds like a loose internal monitor cable?

Answer (score 1):

Would going to sleep then waking by pressing space?

`pmi action hibernate; sleep 1; xdotool key space`

Comment: When the system is hibernated, software is not running anymore. So neither will your Bash script, probably.

Comment: The `;` after the hibernate command means that `sleep` and commands after that will only be run after the `pmi...` command is complete, likely when the computer has woken up from hibernation...

Comment: @wilf would && be better?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a hardware issue than anything else, but here it goes.
Two possible solutions I can think of;

- Press CTRL+ALT+F1, wait a few seconds, press CTRL+ALT+F2. On many systems this will change the resolution of the display, which is probably enough to reactivate it if it's not indeed just a loose contact (in which case nothing you do with the software is going to help you anyway).
- There's probably a key combination built into your laptop for turning on and off the monitor. Something like Fn+F. It's probably indicated on one of the F keys. Try turning off your display and turning it on again.

Either way, you should probably fight the problem at its core, which is the hardware. Although I understand this can be an expensive affair.